# What's the cleanest way to create minimalistic ASPX page with Response.Write

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest

I need to create a super small web interface which I could use to retrieve data from web server.

Kinda like:

```
http://smartserver/?question=IsGrassGreen
```

With a response:

```
yes
```

I don't want, or need, to add all that soap envelope overhead, so I'm thinking of leaving the Default.aspx blank, aside from top line <%@ blablabla %>, viewstate disable, sessionstate disable, and that's it.

The question is, what do I have to do in codebehind? IIRC, Page_Load executes very far from entry point, and generates gobs of unnecessary processing, so there should be a better place to write `Response.Clear`, `Response.Write`, `Response.Flush` etc. But it has been 3+ years since I've done ASP.

Is there another, cleaner, smarter alternative to what I want to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid the overhead of the Page Life Cycle, how about you implement an [HTTP Handler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001) for all requests and carry out the processing there?

- [Further documentation on MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307985)
- [An example handler by Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABoilerplateHttpHandler.aspx)

Comment: Hmm, looks good. But from where you start to create that handler? New Project-> New Web Site? New Service? New Assembly? Tutorials so far are not clear. Do I deploy only Web.config + httphandlerassembly.dll?

Comment: Should be fine starting with an empty ASP.NET Application and setting up the Handler in the web.config. Hope the source you've found provides the right info.

Comment: Yes, empty page, add generic handler, works like a charm. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

For a minimal website like this, we created an ASP.NET MVC website with no views at all. The controller simply returns plain old content.

Something like:

```
public class QuestionController : Controller
{
     public string ShowAnswer(string question)
     {
         // handle your logic
         return "yes";
      }
}
```

Then you can query your method by an URL like:

http://mysite/question/ShowAnswer/IsGrassGreen

Or you can take a look the [Nancy](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy) framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASP.Net "WebMethod" to achieve your requirement in simple. This will avoid page cycles etc..

Refer this link 
http://weblogs.asp.net/karan/archive/2010/09/12/calling-server-side-method-using-jquery-ajax.aspx